# NetworkManager (applet) - After click on network no window or error

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, networkmanager, intel

I have a problem with NetworkManger, or to be specific with the nm-applet. 
When I choose the WiFi network I want to connect to nothing happens. The terminal window I opened nm-applet shows some warnings and errors, but I don't think that they have something to do with the actual problem:

> ```
> nm-applet (nm-applet:1442): 
> nm-applet-WARNING **: Error connecting to ModemManager: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.ModemManager1: 
> GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.Load Failed: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.service failed to load: No such file or directory. 
> ** Message: Remote error from secret service: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any .service files
> ```

I know that one error occurs because I don't have installed the notification tool that is needed for the GNOME notifications.

NetworkManager's service is running. My wifi on-board card is an Intel Pro/Wireless 5100 AGN (it uses the iwlwifi driver).
My distribution is Arch Linux and I'm using the awesome WM.

Comment: Yep, modem manager is fine and unrelated to your topic. Try attach something useful from `/var/log/messages`, you will see more information from NetworkManager

Comment: Try going through these things: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingNetworkManager

Answer (score 4):

Installing `gnome-keyring` solved the problem for me.